# Archive's total file size a lot bigger than the total file size of all its contents

Tags: 7-zip, winrar

I'm currently browsing through the content of a `.obb` archive containing the game files for an old Android game. Upon extracting its contents, I noticed that the total data size of the `.obb` archive did not match the total data size of all the files stored into it (1.24 GB  vs.  229 MB).

As the game in question is in 3D, I doubt that the entirety of the game's resources are worth a mere 300 MB. But then that would mean that the rest of the data is somehow hidden. I've tried using both 7-zip and winRAR, but got the same exact result every time.

Would anyone here, by any chance, know how to retrieve this missing data?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: [Related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55215427/how-to-extract-open-game-obb-files-in-windows-pc)